# No email message when attachment is sent

Tags: server, email, postfix

I am writing a script that sends log files via the terminal to my email address. It appears, that when I'm using the `-A` flag, the message itself does not show in the email.

```
echo "This is the message I want to be shown in the email, but it does not appear." | mail -s "any subject" -A <path to attachement> mail@example.com
```

Here is a snippet from the script that may make the situation clearer:

```
mail='mail@example.com'
log="/var/log/apt/$(date +"%Y%m%d")-apt-update.log"
echo "Update done" | mail -s "update done" -A $log $mail
```

When I am sending the mail without `-A` and without the attachment (only with the subject) then the message I am echoing does appear.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This works for my daily backup:

```
mail -a "$Filename64" -s "$Filename64" "$EmailAddr" < BackupLog
```

So for your case try:

```
mail='mail@example.com'
log="/var/log/apt/$(date +"%Y%m%d")-apt-update.log"
echo "Update done" > /tmp/MessageBody
mail -a "$log" -s "update done" "$mail" < /tmp/MessageBody
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me either. There is still no message in the mail. And I guess the flag u meant was '-A'. Since '-a' is for appending headers.

Comment: I just noticed `MessageBody` was spelled wrong the second time. I've changed it.

Comment: Must it be named 'MessageBody' or is it just for your example?

Comment: Just my example where I had spelled it differently second time...

Comment: Well i guess dumb question of me, tested it anyway with different spellings... sorry for that.
Unfortunately this still does not work for me :(
But it's actually not that important, just a "nice to have". Since those mails are just for me and for messing around with stuff. I guess I will just leave this issue for the moment.

Comment: OK well if you ever revisit the issue rest assured it does work. Every morning my important files are backed up, compressed and emailed to gmail.com as an attachment using the `mail` command and the message body contains a file listing.

Comment: Maybe the mailserver is blocking the messages. I do not send to gmail.